# Sending notificaton for multi chat in a chat application

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmpp

I am developing a chat application using XMPP/JQuery. In a chat application, for 
    a multi chat task, first a request has to be made to a member to participate in 
    the multi chat. How can i accomplish this.

Comment: Please go back through your old questions and accept some answers. You'll find people are far more likely to answer your questions.

Comment: I mean the stanza for sending a request to a particular user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking how to invite someone to a Multi-User Chat room, read [XEP-0045, section 7.5](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#invite).  If you need to invite Google users, send a direct invite:

```
<message
    from='darkcave@chat.shakespeare.lit'
    to='hecate@shakespeare.lit'>
  <x xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user'>
    <invite from='crone1@shakespeare.lit/desktop'>
      <reason>
        Hey Hecate, this is the place for all good witches!
      </reason>
    </invite>
    <password>cauldronburn</password>
  </x>
</message>
```

Otherwise, go through the room:

```
<message
    from='crone1@shakespeare.lit/desktop'
    to='darkcave@chat.shakespeare.lit'>
  <x xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user'>
    <invite to='hecate@shakespeare.lit'>
      <reason>
        Hey Hecate, this is the place for all good witches!
      </reason>
    </invite>
  </x>
</message>
```

Comment: How to implement the above stanzas in Jquery?

Comment: jQuery isn't an XMPP library.  Are you using Strophe.js?

Comment: Here's a link to the strophe.js docs: http://strophe.im/strophejs/doc/1.0.2/files2/strophe-js.html
start:
$msg({to: 'darkcave@chat.shakespeare.lit'}).c('x', {xmlns:'http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user'}) $
etc.

Comment: One more doubt, what will be the response from server for such stanza?

Comment: And how to handle the response?